# Icon Hover effect made with divs, Margin Issue

Tags: html, css, hover

Here's [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJdK7/):

```css
#facebookIcon{ 
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:white;
    font-size:5.5em;

    opacity:0.4; 
}

#facebookinner:hover  #facebookIcon{
    opacity:1.0;
}

#facebookinner{

    background:#3b5998;
    border-radius:100px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px; 

    opacity:0.4;
    -webkit-transition:
}

#facebookinner:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}

#facebookouter {  
  background-color:Green;
  border:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;

 -webkit-transition: height 0.2s linear, width 0.2s linear,border 0.2s ease-out,border-                   radius 0.2s     linear,margin 0.2s linear;
  transition: height 0.2s linear, width 0.2s linear,border 0.2s ease-out,border-radius 0.2s     linear,margin 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.2s linear, width 0.2s linear,border 0.2s ease-out,border-radius 0.2s     linear,margin 0.2s linear;
}

#facebookouter:hover {
    height:130px;
    width:130px;
    border-radius:130px;
    border:5px solid #3b5998;
    opacity:1.0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.2s linear, width 0.2s linear,border 0.2s ease-                    out,border-radius 0.2s linear,margin 0.2s linear;
    transition: height 0.2s linear, width 0.2s linear,border 0.2s ease-out,border-radius 0.2s linear,margin 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.2s linear, width 0.2s linear,border 0.2s ease-out,border-radius 0.2s linear,margin 0.2s linear;   
}

footer {

 margin-top:250px;
 height:150px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 10;
 left: 0;
 padding: 5 rem;
 background-color: Green;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top:30px;
 padding-left:40px;
}
```

/****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****Here is the Second Icon****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___***/

```css
    #twitterIcon{
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:white;
    font-size:3.5em;
    -webkit-transition:font-size 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:font-size 0.2s;
     transition:font-size 0.2s;
 }

 #twitterinner:hover  #twitterIcon{
    opacity:1.0;
    font-size: 3.5 em
 }

 #twitterinner {
    background:#23dcd5;
    border-radius:100px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px; 


    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s, width 0.2s, line-height 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s, width 0.2s, line-height 0.2s;
    transition:height 0.2s, width 0.2s, line-height 0.2s;
}

#twitterinner:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
    height: 80px;
    width:80px;
    line-height:80px;
}

#twitterouter{    
background-color:Green;
border:5px solid #23dcd5;
height:100px;
width:100px;
border-radius:100px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
opacity:0.7;
}

#twitterouter:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

I`m a beginner in CSS (1 week of learning) and I saw this hover effect (at the bottom of [this page](http://smarchal.com/twbscolor/?bd=e74c3c&bh=c0392b&cd=ecf0f1&ch=ffbbbc) for the Social Icons).

So I tried to make the same hover effect with my limited skills. After a long time I made the same effect with two divs and an Icon.

The Problem is now that:

1. Im not able to set a margin to any of the "Icons", this means i want a gap between the FacebookIcon and the TwitterIcon so they wont interfere like the FacebookIcon is interfering with the Twitter Icon.
2. How can I hover over the inner div and activating the hover of the outer div (I can not make the inner div the parent of the outer because the outer has to be bigger than the inner).
3. I want the FacebookIcon Outer to grow from the center and not like its doing now. (Like in the example in the Webpage mentioned above.

I've searched for this solutions long time and found nothing suitable. Probably there is a much easier way of creating this Icons, this would be another solution :)

Thanks for your advice and sorry for my bad English (German here).

Comment: I made [TWBSColor](http://smarchal.com/twbscolor/), thanks for using/sharing it ;) Don't hesitate to send me a mail for any question related to my websites style/code/usage/anything (but I see here you already have your answer !!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Im not able to set a margin to any of the "Icons"

That's because `margin` property [is not applicable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin) to `display: table-cell` elements.

> How can I hover over the inner div and activating the hover of the
>   outer div

*Well,* you need to change your strategy. Set all the necessary CSS declarations on the child (`<i>` tag) and change the styles on `parent:hover i` selector.

Here we go:

**HTML:**

```html
<footer>
    <a href="#" class="icon-wrapper">
        <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="icon-wrapper"> 
        <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>
    </a>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.icon-wrapper {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 1.875rem;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5.5rem;
}

.icon-wrapper i.icon {
    display: block;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 8rem;
    line-height: 8rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.icon-wrapper:hover i.icon {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5625rem green,  /* <-- = the parent's background-color */
                0 0 0 1.875rem #9b59b6;
}

.icon-facebook {
    background-color: #3b5998;
}

.icon-twitter {
    background-color: #23dcd5;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/LJdK7/2/)**.

Comment: First, thank you so far this was a big help. But now I don`t know how to make the second effect with this icon classes like I did with the Twitter Icon. Would be nice if you could show me how to achive this effect :) If there is any link which answers my question it would be fine too.

Comment: @user3262728 Sorry for the late response. Here's my attempt to implement the effect; Hope this help: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/LJdK7/4/